# Google vision API giving sporadic 403 errors

Tags: api, google-cloud-vision

I have a very basic python app that calls the google vision API and asks for OCR on an image.

It was working fine a few days ago using a basic API key. I have since created a modified version that uses a service account as well, which also worked.

All my images are ~500kB

However, today about 80% of all calls return "403 reauthorized" when I try to run OCR on the image. The remainder run as they always have done...

The google quotas limit page lists:

```
MB per image    4 MB
MB per request  8 MB
Requests per second 10
Requests per feature per day    700,000
Requests per feature per month  20,000,000
Images per second   8
Images per request  16
```

And I am way below any of these limits (by orders of magnitude) - any idea what might be going on?

It seems strange that simply running the same code, with the same input images, will sometimes give a 403 and sometimes not....perhaps the error is indicative of the API struggling with demand?

Comment: I've been having a similar issue, with > 80% of my calls return a 403 Request Issue Failed since 2 days ago, having worked for months with no issue previously. Trying again sometime later, it works fine. I'm using GCS, and the files are uploaded right before the call, so I thought it might be a consistency issue but GCS is supposed to be strongly consistent for these types of requests. Hopefully it's just a weekend glitch.

Comment: For what it's worth, the issue now seems to have gone away and all my requests are now returning data correctly. Hopefully you've experienced the same!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dave - yes, I have. After much debugging at my end, it seems it was the API that was up the spout :-) All fine now...